# SoundChannel, removeEventHandler, AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a better way to use the sound channel is AS3? This works, but I hate it when I tap the play button twice and it starts doubling. Please advise.

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
playButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, myPlayButtonHandler);
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
        function myPlayButtonHandler (e:MouseEvent):void {

            myChannel = mySound.play();
            }
stopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickStop);
        function onClickStop(e:MouseEvent):void{
            myChannel.stop();
            }

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//global sound buttons, add instance of 'killswitch' and 'onswitch' to stage
killswitch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clipKillSwitch); 
        function clipKillSwitch(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
var transform1:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();
transform1.volume=0;
flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform=transform1;
            }       
onswitch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clipOnSwitch); 
        function clipOnSwitch(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
var transform1_:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();        
transform1_.volume=1;
flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform=transform1_;      
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `removeEventListener()` to detach `myPlayButtonHandler` for the duration of the sound.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
playButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, myPlayButtonHandler);
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
        function myPlayButtonHandler (e:MouseEvent):void {

            myChannel = mySound.play();
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myPlayButtonHandler);
            }
stopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickStop);
        function onClickStop(e:MouseEvent):void{
            myChannel.stop();
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myPlayButtonHandler);

            }

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//global sound buttons, add instance of 'killswitch' and 'onswitch' to stage
killswitch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clipKillSwitch); 
        function clipKillSwitch(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
var transform1:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();
transform1.volume=0;
flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform=transform1;
            }       
onswitch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clipOnSwitch); 
        function clipOnSwitch(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
var transform1_:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();        
transform1_.volume=1;
flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform=transform1_;      
            }
```